# Puppeteer: Is there a trigger that waits until a new element is added?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm new to puppeteer. But basicallyy, I have a list of `tr` and I want to check if there's an added `tr`. If there is, a function will be executed.

I know there's `waitForSelector`, but I'm not sure if it's fit for the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of `tr` that are currently in the `tbody` (or whatever the parent element is) and store the result in a variable. Then trigger the operation that adds the extra row.

Then you can use [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

```
page.waitForSelector(`tbody.the-parent-element > tr:nth-child(${previousCount + 1})`)
```

(Untested, but the principles are solid)